# How can I translate a portion of text I wrote in my language in a browser edit box to another language?

Tags: browser-addons

To write this question, I had to type in the box in english.

I'm looking for an extension or plugin that could allow me to:

- type in my native language
- select the text I typed
- right click and select target language I pre-selected
- selected text get translated
- I submit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the [gTranslate](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gtranslate/) add-on for Firefox?

> With gTranslate you can translate any
>   text in a webpage just by selecting
>   and right-clicking over it. The
>   extension uses the Google translation
>   services to translate the text.
>
> gTranslate is a Firefox extensions
>   which:
>
> **Translates from:**
>
> - English to German / German to English
> - English to Spanish / Spanish to English
> - English to French / French to English
> - English to Italian / Italian to English
> - English to Portuguese / Portuguese to English
> - English to Japanese / Japanese to English
> - English to Korean / Korean to English
> - English to Chinese (Simplified) / Chinese (Simplified) to English
> - English to Arabic / Arabic to English
> - German to French / French to German
> - Auto-detection of browser locale and    page language (if lang
>     attribute is    defined for the
>     selected tag or for    the whole
>     page).
>
> For example: By defalut gTranslate has
>   'German to English' as language pair.
>   If you your locale is set to French
>   then 'German to French' is going to be
>   used, but if the page (or the selected
>   text) is detected to be in English, it
>   will be translated from 'English to
>   French'.
>
> - **Support for translating text from input and textarea form fields. Image 
>     title or alt attributes can be translated also**.

Comment: @Pierre you're most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Or if you use Google Chrome, you can try [Boss Banana](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cgpcplofocmbiacaolpepekdddocefjm#).

To translate text in a field:

- Select text in a field (text area, text input). *The icon in the address bar should be blue.*
- Click the bananas icon in the address bar.
- Click the translation in the popup. *The text should turn green.*

This will replace the selection with the translation.
Click again to cancel.